# Ubuntu 20.04 Tomcat 9 log file

Tags: server

I installed Ubuntu and Tomcat 9. Tomcat logs were written to `syslog` and `catalina.2020-11-25.log` file. I added stdout and stderror lines to the `Tomcat9.service` file.

`tomcat9.service`:

[image: tomcat9.service]

I can see the logs of my project in the `catalina.out` file:

[image: catalina.out]

I can see the tomcat logs in the `catalina.2020.11.25.log` file.

[image: katalina.2020-11-25-log]

I want to write all the logs into `catalina.out` file. How can I do it?

Answer (score 2):

The tomcat9 package on Ubuntu 18.04 and up use a systemd .service file. By default they redirect Tomcat's stdout and stderr to syslog with a prefix tomcat9

To redirect logs to `/var/log/tomcat9/catalina.out`, do this :

```
sudo systemctl edit --full tomcat9.service
```

Modify the logging part as follow:

```
#Logging
StandardOutput=file:/var/log/tomcat9/catalina.out
StandardError=file:/var/log/tomcat9/catalina.out
SyslogIdentifier=tomcat9
```

Restart tomcat9 service.